# Unify identical URL parameters in query string

Tags: php, url-rewriting, get, query-string, url-parameters

I'm fairly new to php and am working on a script for filtering database entries via the GET method. After submitting the form I get URL results like the following (only query_string):

`?mode=compilation&user_filter=Gerhard&user_filter=Harry`

For reasons of shortness and for fitting into the existing script I need the URL formatted **exactly** like this (there's no alternative):

`?mode=compilation&user_filter=Gerhard,Harry`

"user_filter" is the name of the filtering variable. There are two more named "category_filter" and "tag_filter", so the URL could become very long. In addition the existing php script only filters the last user_filter parameter, whereas in the second example, which contains only one user_filter and separates the values by comma, the results are filtered like I wish and contain all postings from the users "Gerhard" and "Harry". This method works perfectly and also in combination with the other two filter variables exactly like intended, when I enter the URL manually, but I need it parsed/rewritten and sent automatically on submitting the form. Thereby the users would be able to select additional names/categories/tags (which are provided in drop-down lists) and add them one by one to the existing parameters as additional comma-separated values.

I suppose I have to receive the string by `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` and manipulate it by utilizing `parse_str()` or something. But how do I get to automatically unifing each additional identically named user_filter-parameter with the one preexisting user_filter-parameter into a comma-separated array of values and sending it to the page?
Or is there an other apporach?

The user, category and tag filters are provided in three separate select forms, each with it's own drop-down list and own submit button. After submitting the page gets reloaded with the new URL parameter and displays the results in an extra html talbe beneath the select forms. Preexisting selections are passed by `input type="hidden"` (hidden input fields), which all works fine.
If I had the solution for the user filter (as an example), I think I would be able to implement it also for the other two filter variables.

Regards
Taurec

Comment: the fact that you want comma separated variables and are using PHP is a bit odd. Usually you would do `<input name="user_filter[]"` for array inputs and PHP will parse them as arrays

Comment: I know. I'm heavy editing a third party script for private purpose and for some reason, that I don't understand at this time, it won't accept array inputs. (_"error in your SQL syntax..."_) I seems to have something to do with how the software handels existing variable names as part of the pretty complex SQL query.

Comment: To do it as I described certain would be less extensive than revisiting the hole script (with unpredictable and unacceptable consequences for other functions).